# Azure Text To Speech - How to create a sentence using a local language and including one English term?

Tags: azure, text-to-speech

I am using Azure Text-to-Speech to convert Indonesian sentences into audio format. The problem is, there are several English terms within the sentence. How can I make those terms be pronounced in English by the same speaker?

I used azure speech studio audio content creation SMML. Bellow is my SMML

```
<!--ID=B7267351-473F-409D-9765-754A8EBCDE05;Version=1|{"VoiceNameToIdMapItems":[{"Id":"6eae597f-b880-47c8-bbe6-f05e69fbdf9d","Name":"Microsoft Server Speech Text to Speech Voice (id-ID, ArdiNeural)","ShortName":"id-ID-ArdiNeural","Locale":"id-ID","VoiceType":"StandardVoice"}]}-->
<!--ID=FCB40C2B-1F9F-4C26-B1A1-CF8E67BE07D1;Version=1|{"Files":{}}-->
<!--ID=5B95B1CC-2C7B-494F-B746-CF22A0E779B7;Version=1|{"Locales":{"en-GB":{"AutoApplyCustomLexiconFiles":[{}]},"en-US":{"AutoApplyCustomLexiconFiles":[{}]},"fr-CA":{"AutoApplyCustomLexiconFiles":[{}]},"id-ID":{"AutoApplyCustomLexiconFiles":[{}]},"en-SG":{"AutoApplyCustomLexiconFiles":[{}]}}}-->
<speak xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis" xmlns:mstts="http://www.w3.org/2001/mstts" xmlns:emo="http://www.w3.org/2009/10/emotionml" version="1.0" xml:lang="id-ID"><voice name="id-ID-ArdiNeural">lebih mudah dengan menggunakan azure yang mendukung banyak  language dan voice support</voice></speak>
```

in the example above, i want the word "language" to be pronounced in english, not in Indonesia

Comment: Can you check the solution provided in this SO Post -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57516590/azure-speech-to-text-translations-with-multiple-languages

Comment: Also, It would be helpful for me, If you update the code in your question? So I understand which framework you're using!

Comment: @SiddheshDesai i used azure speech studio audio content creation SSML

Comment: Can you try this code in your SSML - <speak xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis" xmlns:mstts="http://www.w3.org/2001/mstts" xmlns:emo="http://www.w3.org/2009/10/emotionml" version="1.0" xml:lang="id-ID">
<voice name="id-ID-ArdiNeural">lebih mudah dengan menggunakan azure yang mendukung banyak <phoneme alphabet="x-microsoft-ups" ph="ˈlæŋɡwɪdʒ">language</phoneme> dan voice support</voice>
</speak>

Comment: @SiddheshDesai thank you, i can make it works by modify your suggestion to become like this <phoneme alphabet="ipa" ph="læŋɡwɪdʒ">language</phoneme>. So is it means that i need to change every english words appears on my sentence?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The "phoneme" tag must be used to describe the phonetic pronunciation of each English word. As, Audio content creation tool in Speech studio does not yet support any feature to add multiple language as an output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed over comments,

You can use the "phoneme" tag in your SSML to specify the pronunciation of the English terms in your Indonesian sentence.

To make the word "language" be pronounced in English, you can add the following line of code within the  tag:

```xml
<speak xmlns="w3.org/2001/10/synthesis" xmlns:mstts="w3.org/2001/mstts" xmlns:emo="w3.org/2009/10/emotionml" version="1.0" xml:lang="id-ID"> <voice name="id-ID-ArdiNeural">lebih mudah dengan menggunakan azure yang mendukung banyak <phoneme alphabet="ipa" ph="ˈlæŋɡwɪdʒ">language</phoneme> dan voice support</voice> </speak>
```

***Output:-***

[image]

[image]

> **Note:-**
> The "phoneme" tag must be used to describe the phonetic pronunciation of each English word. As, Audio content creation tool in Speech studio does not yet support any feature to add multiple language as an output